# remove spacing between divs, bootstrap

Tags: c#, html, css, .net, twitter-bootstrap

I have used Twitter Bootstrap to separate the `<div>` as follows

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:10px;">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="border-style:dotted;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                <label>Period:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-8 col-md-offset-1 col-md-7 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-6">
                @Html.DropDownList("Period", new List<SelectListItem>() {
                    new SelectListItem{Text = "Last 7 Days", Value = "6"},
                    new SelectListItem{Text = "Last 15 Days", Value = "14"},
                    new SelectListItem{Text = "Last 30 Days", Value = "29"},
                    new SelectListItem{Text = "Last 90 Days", Value = "89"},
                    new SelectListItem{Text = "Last 180 Days", Value = "179"},
                    new SelectListItem{Text = "Last 365 Days", Value = "364", Selected = true},
                    new SelectListItem{Text = "Custom", Value = "0"}
                })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="border-style:solid;">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-6  col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
               <input type="text" id="FromDatePicker" readonly="readonly" placeholder="From Date" style="display: none; width: 78px;  line-height: 25px;">
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
               <input type="text" id="ToDatePicker" readonly="readonly" placeholder="To Date" style="display: none; width: 78px;  line-height: 25px; ">
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

As can be seen, I have divided the `row` `<div>` in `6-6`. When i reduce screen to small size the divs appear as shown in the attached image. I want the extra space to be removed when the screen is in `XS` or `SM` mode.[image: 2nd line in image is what i want]

Comment: this is due to the fixed width to the date-picker input fields

Comment: make the date-picker divs 100% with on mobile devices using media queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<div class="row row-no-padding" style="padding-top:10px;">

.row-no-padding [class*="col-"] {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Or just for xs/sm:

```
.row-no-padding [class*="col-xs"],
.row-no-padding [class*="col-sm"] {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error of missing selector. Is this the exact syntax.?

Comment: Sorry, forgot I was using the LESS syntax. :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that . A new style sheet is being used when you view it in small screen .

HOW TO FIX :

1. Test it is browser with responsive utilities. Select low screen.
2. Open firebug. Go to the element. Click on search icon on top. Select the element it will show which css is being used.
3. Remove the padding from that css.

It should fix the issue